# c++ concert memory exception for LP

Tags: c++, memory, cplex

I used c++/concert technology to code an algorithm that involves solving a huge number of LP problems. When I increase the size of the problem, I get " Concert exception caught: not enough memory".

I am doing the tests on a computer with 8Gb of Ram. I monitored my memory usage (in task manager) for so many instances and the memory usage never goes above 1.8 Gb. However, at that point I get the memory error.

Is there any explanation for that? I tried to adjust the memory that CPLEX can use, but all settings are for MIP problems and not LP.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you compiling for 32 or 64 bit? Looking through their examples, I see a lot of "copyright xxx -2003", which is why I ask...

Comment: My computer is 64 bit, but the version of my CPLEX installation is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that the process that allocates memory is 32-bit, so it cannot allocate more than 2 Gb of memory.
Even if the process is technically 64-bit, there could be some bitness issues in the code, limiting memory consumption to 2 Gb again.

Comment: I switched to 64 bit version of Cplex. That resolved the issue. Thanks